# JAXWS SOAP Response Schema

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, jaxb

I am in the process of moving an older web service that had dependency on Weblogic 8 (servicegen) to a JAX WS implementation using annotations.    I used the existing WSDL and JAXB to generate the data objects (marshalling/unmarshalling).  However, I notice a difference in the SOAP response that is now being generated with JAXWS.  I need to generate the same response, as there are over 900 clients, and can’t ask them to modify their code to use the new response schema.

The existing response looks like this:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <env:Header/>
   <env:Body>
      <m:findAllCertInfoByOwnerResponse xmlns:m="http://uum.webservices.com">
         <n1:result xsi:type="n2:ArrayOfWSCertInfo" xmlns:n1="http://uum.webservices.com" xmlns:n2="java:com.service.data">
            <n2:WSCertInfo>
               <n2:CPCreateDate> </n2:CPCreateDate>
               <n2:CPExpireDate> </n2:CPExpireDate>
               <n2:CPStatus> </n2:CPStatus>
               <n2:PrevUniqueId>123456</n2:PrevUniqueId>
               <n2:UniqueId></n2:UniqueId>
               <n2:certID xsi:nil="true"/>
               <n2:certStatus/>
               <n2:endDate xsi:nil="true"/>
               <n2:issuerDN> </n2:issuerDN>
               <n2:owner></n2:owner>
               <n2:profileName> </n2:profileName>
               <n2:renewalStatus xsi:nil="true"/>
               <n2:revokeReason/>
               <n2:serialNo xsi:nil="true"/>
               <n2:startDate xsi:nil="true"/>
               <n2:subjectDN xsi:nil="true"/>
               <n2:validCertificate>false</n2:validCertificate>
               <n2:validEnrollment>true</n2:validEnrollment>
            </n2:WSCertInfo>
          </n1:result>
      </m:findAllCertInfoByOwnerResponse>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

The new JAX WS SOAP response has the following format:

```
    <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:findLatestCertInfoByOwnerResponse xmlns:ns3="java:com.service.data" xmlns:ns2="http://uum.webservices.com">
         <result>
            <ns2:result>
               <ns3:WSCertInfo>
                  <ns3:CPCreateDate xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <ns3:CPExpireDate xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <ns3:CPStatus xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <ns3:PrevUniqueId>123456</ns3:PrevUniqueId>
                  <ns3:UniqueId xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <ns3:certID xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <ns3:certStatus xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <ns3:endDate xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <ns3:issuerDN xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <ns3:owner xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <ns3:profileName xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <ns3:renewalStatus xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <ns3:revokeReason xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <ns3:serialNo xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <ns3:startDate xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <ns3:subjectDN xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <ns3:validCertificate>false</ns3:validCertificate>
                  <ns3:validEnrollment>false</ns3:validEnrollment>
               </ns3:WSCertInfo>
            </ns2:result>
         </result>
      </ns2:findLatestCertInfoByOwnerResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

The JAXWS SOAP response is pretty close  except for the following:

1. JAXWS response  is missing the xsi:type and xmlns info.  Plus it is nested in the  attribute.

How can I add the xsi:type and xmlns to the  attribute?

I am including the example class to show the defined web annotations.

Thanks in advance for your assistance!!!!!

The Web Service class looks like the following:

```
@WebService(
        name            = "UUMCertLocatorService", 
        serviceName     = "UUMCertLocatorService", 
        portName        = "UUMCertLocatorServicePort", 
        targetNamespace = "http://uum.webservices.com",
        wsdlLocation    = "UUMCertLocatorService.wsdl")

@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED,
             style          = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT,
             use            = SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL)

public class UUMCertLocatorServiceEndPoint {

    @WebMethod(action="",operationName="findLatestCertInfoByOwner")
    @WebResult(name="findLatestCertInfoByOwnerResponse",header=true,targetNamespace="java:com.service.data",partName="http://uum.webservices.com")
    public FindAllCertInfoByOwnerResponse findAllCertInfoByOwner(

            @WebParam(targetNamespace="http://uum.webservices.com", 
            partName="http://uum.webservices.com",
            name="string")String uniqueID,

            @WebParam(targetNamespace="http://uum.webservices.com", 
            partName="http://uum.webservices.com",
            name="string0")String adminSessionSpec,

            @WebParam(targetNamespace="http://uum.webservices.com", 
            partName="http://uum.webservices.com",
            name="string1")String webKey) throws WSUUMException
    {

        LogHelper.debug(UUMCertLocatorServiceEndPoint.class, "Params: {}  {} {} ", uniqueID,adminSessionSpec,webKey);

        final ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
        FindAllCertInfoByOwnerResponse response = objectFactory.createFindAllCertInfoByOwnerResponse();
        WSCertInfo certinfo = objectFactory.createWSCertInfo();
        certinfo.setBofaPrevUniqueId("123456");

        ArrayOfWSCertInfo arraycert = objectFactory.createArrayOfWSCertInfo();
        arraycert.getWSCertInfo().add(certinfo);

       response.setResult(arraycert);
       return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to post the WSDL and associated XSD Files?